# Django redirect after user successfully logs in

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I want to redirect the user after successful login. Currently, I'm doing it this way. PS: I don't want to use Django Forms. Is the way I'm doing this the standard way of redirecting the user?

**HTML**

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sender-email" class="control-label">Username:</label>
        <div class="input-icon"> <i class="icon-user fa"></i>
            <input id="sender-email" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user-pass" class="control-label">Password:</label>
        <div class="input-icon"> <i class="icon-lock fa"></i>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="user-pass">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="authenticate_user">Submit</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

**js**

```
$(function(){
    $('#authenticate_user').click(function(){
        username = $('#sender-email').val();
        password = $('#user-pass').val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url: '/login',
            data: {'username':username, 'password':password},
            success : function(result){
                window.location = '/';
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            },
        });
    })
})
```

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('%s' % (settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL))
            else:
                return {'error': 'Your account has been disabled.'}
        else:
            return {'error': 'Invalid Login.'}

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('%s' % (settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL))

    ctx = {}
    return render(request, 'login/login.html', ctx)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly OK but I would say you may need to incorporate a redirect query parameter because frequently, you are faced with a situation that the client tries to access a resource on the server and because she is unauthenticated, she is redirected to the login url with the original resource URI as a query parameter. Post-successful login, the web server will redirect the client to the original resource she had been trying to access.

Comment: How can I redirect via Django view itself. I mean when jQuery is itself re-directing the user to `/` page, then whats the need for `return redirect('%s' % (settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL))`? How can I redirect from the django view itself?

Comment: You have to distinguish between return status 200 vs 301, 302